# Validating an external certificate not in certifi package

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I have a Python script that requests an `https` URL using the `requests` package. In so doing, I get a certificate error:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://comicskingdom.com/', verify=True)
```

The error I see is:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
```

My system has the **certifi** package installed, but apparently the target server's certificate cannot be validated using that package's bundle. How can I verify this certificate properly? Where do I look to download the appropriate certificate chain? In the future, how do I know where to find the right certificate chain for any given certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/
(check args and kwargs possibilities (cert=...) in chapter **SSL Cert Verification**)

but to quickly resolve your issue:

1. (Firefox) go to your site. Click on the https icon left to the browser url (usually the icon looks like a lock),click on an arrow next to 'connection secure', click more info, click **View certificates** and scroll down to download Chain certificate. (You can even try here on stackoverflow site)

[image]

Then, in your requests.get, add path to the chain file

```
>>> requests.get('https://comicskingdom.com', verify='{path}/comicskingdom-com-chain.pem')

<Response [200]>
```

The certificate has some issue, so I will post here what I was able to find

**What is problem?**

What exactly is a problem can be found through this link or through finding the error

Source: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/how-to-get-public-key-of-a-secure-webpage

for you to examine the problem, run this command

This command will show you the certificate is ok, but there is issue

```
openssl s_client -connect comicskingdom.com:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```

which outputs

```
openssl s_client -connect comicskingdom.com:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.comicskingdom.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.comicskingdom.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

**Note** this part

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

which matches requests error that I received with requests

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='comicskingdom.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thank you!